# Plot chart before script end

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, spyder

I have a problem with ploting in Python

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.plot(np.arange(10),np.arange(10))
plt.show(0)
#another computation
```

I am using Spyder editor with graphic backend set to automatic. I want to make plot in new window. The problem is the plot appear after the end of the script. How to make it appear immediately?

Comment: you could try to set `plt.ioff()` before the script

Comment: It doesn't work. When I set "inline" in graphic backend options it works OK but I want to plot in another windows